# Do Laravel or Rails MYSQL Queries from ORM use JOIN Statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, laravel, eloquent

Simple question but I can't seem to find an answer...
Given the following statement:

```
$phone = User::find(1)->phone()->first();
```

According to Laravel, it seems like this will generate two SQL statements instead of using a JOIN. Is is it like this in all PHP frameworks? What about rails?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel does use additional SELECT statements to fetch related models, you can see these if you turn on the Profiler.  I have seen remarks that say it's considered more efficient than a JOIN but I'm sure there are cleverer people who can explain why/why not.

I do know, that if you're fetching a lot of related data (i.e. in a loop) that you should look into using Laravel's Eager Loading feature to minimise queries.

Comment: I'd be super curious to know how multiple SELECT statements can be more efficient then JOIN (since I always thought that was one of the main points of SQL databases?) I don't really like writing/reading JOIN statements though so I'm all for their demise.

Comment: Read my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130338/laravel-really-struggling-to-understand-eloquent/14138004#14138004 that addresses my reasons why this is better than a join.